# Removing a nan from a list

Tags: python, list, nan

While trying to work on a project with pandas I have run into a problem. I had a list with a `nan` value in it and I couldn’t remove it.

I have tried:

```py
incoms=data['int_income'].unique().tolist()
incoms.remove('nan')
```

But it didn't work:

```
list.remove(x): x not in list"
```

The list `incoms` is as follows:

```
[75000.0, 50000.0, 0.0, 200000.0, 100000.0, 25000.0, nan, 10000.0, 175000.0, 150000.0, 125000.0]
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you can do is simply get a cleaned list where you don't put the values that, once converted to strings, are 'nan'.

The code would be :

```
incoms = [incom for incom in incoms if str(incom) != 'nan']
```

Comment: you really should use `math.isnan` and not rely on implementation details, like `str(float("nan")) == "nan"`'

Answer (score 25):

I think you need [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html) for remove `NaN`s:

```
incoms=data['int_income'].dropna().unique().tolist()
print (incoms)
[75000.0, 50000.0, 0.0, 200000.0, 100000.0, 25000.0, 10000.0, 175000.0, 150000.0, 125000.0]
```

And if all values are integers only:

```
incoms=data['int_income'].dropna().astype(int).unique().tolist()
print (incoms)
[75000, 50000, 0, 200000, 100000, 25000, 10000, 175000, 150000, 125000]
```

Or remove `NaN`s by selecting all non NaN values by [`numpy.isnan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html):

```
a = data['int_income'].unique()
incoms= a[~np.isnan(a)].tolist()
print (incoms)
[75000.0, 50000.0, 0.0, 200000.0, 100000.0, 25000.0, 10000.0, 175000.0, 150000.0, 125000.0]
```

---

```
a = data['int_income'].unique()
incoms= a[~np.isnan(a)].astype(int).tolist()
print (incoms)
[75000, 50000, 0, 200000, 100000, 25000, 10000, 175000, 150000, 125000]
```

Pure python solution - slowier if big `DataFrame`:

```
incoms=[x for x in  list(set(data['int_income'])) if pd.notnull(x)]
print (incoms)
[0.0, 100000.0, 200000.0, 25000.0, 125000.0, 50000.0, 10000.0, 150000.0, 175000.0, 75000.0]
```

---

```
incoms=[int(x) for x in  list(set(data['int_income'])) if pd.notnull(x)]
print (incoms)
[0, 100000, 200000, 25000, 125000, 50000, 10000, 150000, 175000, 75000]
```

Answer (score 6):

A possibility in that particular case is to remove nans earlier to avoid to do it in the list:

```
incoms=data['int_income'].dropna().unique().tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you arrived at this thread for removing NaNs from a Python list (not pandas dataframes), the easiest way is a list comprehension that filters out NaNs.

```py
import math
new_list = [x for x in my_list if not (isinstance(x, float) and math.isnan(x))]
```

or filter out NaNs by using the fact that NaN is not equal to itself.

```py
new_list = [x for x in my_list if x == x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `nan` in your formula with `numpy.nan` and it will work.

```
import numpy
incoms=data['int_income'].unique().tolist()
incoms.remove(numpy.nan)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).